# Need help cross-compiling nsync using Bazel + Linaro

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to cross-compile [nsync](https://github.com/google/nsync) using Bazel and running into the *exact same* error described in [this question](https://github.com/google/nsync), namely:

```
.///platform/c++11/platform.h:29:17: fatal error: mutex: No such file or directory
```

The person who posted that question appears to have been working from the same [Bazel cross-build tutorial](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain) as me, but they reached a very different conclusion about the root cause (i.e., they claim it was user error due to a mistyped include path). In my case, all the paths are correct, but they're being ignored/overridden by nsync's build. I could really use some help figuring out what changes are needed to make nsync build correctly with the Linaro toolchain.

Here's a small script that reproduces the problem 100% of the time on my system:

```
#!/bin/bash     
# File: repro-nsync-error.sh
set -euo pipefail

# Work in a temp folder
mkdir tempxxx && cd tempxxx

# Clone the bits 
git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel.git
git clone https://github.com/google/nsync.git

# Copy custom toolchain example files from the Bazel toolchain tutorial into nsync project
cd nsync
cp -a ../bazel/src/test/shell/bazel/testdata/bazel_toolchain_test_data/compilers .
cp -a ../bazel/src/test/shell/bazel/testdata/bazel_toolchain_test_data/tools/arm_compiler ./tools
cat ../bazel/src/test/shell/bazel/testdata/bazel_toolchain_test_data/WORKSPACE.linaro >> ./WORKSPACE

# Set executable bit on wrapper scripts
chmod +x ./tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-*

# Nix the `.linaro` extension that the Bazel project uses to 'hide' the
# example files during normal Bazel builds, otherwise Bazel won't 'see' them 
for file in $(find -name "*.linaro"); do mv "${file}" "$(dirname ${file})/$(basename ${file%.*})"; done 

# Attempt to build
bazel build --verbose_failures --crosstool_top=//tools/arm_compiler:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a //:nsync_cpp
```

And here's the output I get when I run it:

```
$ ./repro-nsync-error.sh 
Cloning into 'bazel'...
remote: Counting objects: 305983, done.     
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (184/184), done.
remote: Total 305983 (delta 127), reused 273 (delta 104), pack-reused 305624
Receiving objects: 100% (305983/305983), 457.28 MiB | 2.62 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (188973/188973), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Cloning into 'nsync'...
remote: Counting objects: 944, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Total 944 (delta 10), reused 23 (delta 7), pack-reused 910
Receiving objects: 100% (944/944), 316.81 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (496/496), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
.........
INFO: Analysed target //:nsync_cpp (10 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/evadeflow/Desktop/tempxxx/nsync/BUILD:463:1: C++ compilation of rule '//:nsync_cpp' failed (Exit 1): arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/evadeflow/.cache/bazel/_bazel_evadeflow/595bcf82ccc39f6a61512641b728b082/execroot/__main__ && \ 
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/evadeflow/.virtualenvs/tfbootstrap/bin:/home/evadeflow/.local/bin:/home/evadeflow/.virtualenvs/tfbootstrap/bin:/home/evadeflow/.local/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/home/evadeflow/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/home/evadeflow/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/evadeflow/bin:/home/evadeflow/bin:/home/evadeflow/bin:/home/evadeflow/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc '--sysroot=external/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc' '-mfloat-abi=hard' -nostdinc -isystem external/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.3.1/include -isystem external/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include -isystem external/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.3.1/include-fixed -isystem external/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -fPIE '-fdiagnostics-color=always' -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -MD -MF bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-fastbuild/bin/_objs/nsync_cpp/internal/dll.pic.d -fPIC -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-fastbuild/genfiles -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-fastbuild/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -isystem public -isystem bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-fastbuild/genfiles/public -isystem bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-fastbuild/bin/public -x c++ '-std=c++11' -DNSYNC_ATOMIC_CPP11 -DNSYNC_USE_CPP11_TIMEPOINT -I.///platform/c++11 -I.///platform/gcc -I.///platform/arm -I.///public -I.///internal -I.///platform/posix '-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L' -pthread -no-canonical-prefixes -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c internal/dll.c -o bazel-out/armeabi-v7a-fastbuild/bin/_objs/nsync_cpp/internal/dll.pic.o)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
In file included from internal/dll.c:16:0:
.///platform/c++11/platform.h:29:17: fatal error: mutex: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Target //:nsync_cpp failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 15.023s, Critical Path: 6.77s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I suspect that the Bazel build files for nsync simply aren't written to play nice with the cross-build approach outlined in the Bazel custom toolchain tutorial, but... I don't have enough experience with Bazel to know how to begin punching them into shape...

**UPDATE 1**: I figured out one piece of the puzzle. The files that are failing to compile all appear to have a `.c` extension, implying that they should be 'straight' C sources; however, they wind up including the `platform/c++11/platform.h`, which contains the line:

```
#include <mutex>
```

The `-isystem` flags for the toolchain would switch in the correct include paths—*if* the file were compiled with `g++`. But the fact that they have a `.c` extension means `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` is used instead of `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`, so the `-isystem` flags for C++ aren't being applied, and we wind up getting `fatal error: mutex: No such file or directory`.

As a test of this emerging hypothesis, I wrote this little script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: build.sh
set -euo pipefail                                                                                                                                                                         

bazel build -s --verbose_failures --crosstool_top=//tools/arm_compiler:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a \
  --cxxopt="-isystem external/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.3.1/arm-linux-gnueabihf" \
  --cxxopt="-isystem external/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.3.1" \
  --cxxopt="-isystem external/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/include/c++/5.3.1/arm-linux-gnueabihf" \
  --cxxopt="-isystem external/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/include/c++/5.3.1" \
  //:nsync_cpp
```

When I run this, it fails with the same error, but—if I `s/cxxopt/copt` and `s/isystem /I` as shown below—it compiles successfully:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: build.sh
set -euo pipefail

bazel build -s --verbose_failures --crosstool_top=//tools/arm_compiler:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a \
  --copt="-Iexternal/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.3.1/arm-linux-gnueabihf" \                                                               
  --copt="-Iexternal/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.3.1" \
  --copt="-Iexternal/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/include/c++/5.3.1/arm-linux-gnueabihf" \
  --copt="-Iexternal/org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/include/c++/5.3.1" \
  //:nsync_cpp
```

So... I can definitely see where the 'wrong' compiler flags are being applied. But I'm not sure what the 'right' way to fix the problem is. The above seems like a 'brute force' approach that may have unintended side effects[?], so I'm still searching for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the CROSSTOOL the include directories that contain mutex header are only added to the C++ command lines. I can see how this came to be, the directory where mutex is is `org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.3.1/mutex`, note the `c++`. If you believe that the directory is also valid for C compilation, the principled fix is to change `cxx_flag` into `compiler_flag` in the CROSSTOOL.

You are right in that g++ is not the same as gcc. There is an issue at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4644. But it's not really related to your question, it's only bazel that doesn't put cxx_flags to C compilation command lines, not gcc. Or am I missing something?

And I'd advise not to depend on Bazel test data crosstools :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming—this is _exactly_ how I managed to get around this problem, so I feel obliged to accept your answer.  Can you explain what you mean when you say "I'd advise not to depend on Bazel test data crosstools", though? I'm using this as a starting point because it was the only thing I could _find_. Ultimately, I need to cross-compile tensorflow for arm64 (using a custom Yocto toolchain, not Linaro), and I thought doing it this way first would help me learn how to write the `BUILD` and `CROSSTOOL` files for 'my' toolchain. It's been _stupid_ hard so far—is here some easier way?

Comment: Using it as a starting point it's perfectly fine, I was worried that you depend on its existence in the future.